# Pandas : Two 'isin', one condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I've been using pandas for some months and today I found something weird.

Let's say I have these two dataframes :

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data={'C1' : [1,1,1,2],'C2' : ['A','B','C','D']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data={'C1':[2,2,2],'C2':['A','B','C']})
```

What I want is : from df2, every pairs of {C1,C2} that exist in df1.

This is what I wrote : `df2[df2.C1.isin(df1.C1) & df2.C2.isin(df1.C2)]`

The result I would like to have is an empty dataFrame because in df1, 2 is not linked with 'A','B' or 'C' and what I get is df2. I tried `df2[df2[["C1,"C2"]].isin(df1[["C1,"C2"]])]` but it does not work if df2 has more columns (even if unused).

Comment: note that isin gives u booleans. as such you are working with booleans and not the actual value, as such each condition gives u True for all rows, and when you index, u definitely will get back the same dataframe. zipa's solution offers the right way  to get what u want. just felt i should explain why u had the outcome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with inner `merge`:

```
df2.merge(df1, how='inner', on=['C1', 'C2'])

Empty DataFrame
Columns: [C1, C2]
Index: []
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it works well. Also, I would like to know why two 'isin' in one condition does not work ?

Comment: @Mortimer6969 Your `isin` returns two Series each having all `True` because each element of `df2.C1` is in fact present in `df1.C1`. The same goes for `df2.C2`. What you end up with is two arrays, both having all `True`, that are compared using `&` operator. Needless to say that `True & True` evaluate into `True`.